# Javascript conflict between collapsing navbar and devise routing in Rails 7.0

Tags: javascript, html, routes, navbar

Dear masters in Rails I am struggling to solve a conflict in the head of my app, located in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

My navbar contains a dropdown menu, turns to a toggle button when the screen width reduces. I have the choice between having a non reacting navbar or devise routes not recognised.

I read several posts on the issues in isolation (1 2 3) including setting config.sign_out_via to :get in config/initializers/devise.rb, but I am stuck in making both the navbar menu and the logout work.

I would be grateful to get some insight since I suspect there might be an overlap in the two javascript scripts mentioned below.

1/ Initially a click on a dropdown header did not trigger any thing, until I added the following script in the head:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>`

2/ But in narrow screen mode, when I clicked on the three bar icon in the navbar, it then became irresponsive (not collapsing the menu back). Until I read that this was due to a duplicate calling of javascript, and indeed there was also this line in the head section:
`<%= javascript_include_tag "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>`

So I commented this line out, which makes the navbar behave as expected : in wide screen mode, the dropdown header works all right and in narrow screen mode the toggle works ok too.

3/ But then two new problem arise:

- when I log out a user, I am now getting this error message: > No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
- all the javascript stimulus features I coded do not run anymore.

At this point I have no clue!

Here are my navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-league-box">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
      <%= image_tag "tennis_racket.png" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
      <%# link_to t('.home_link'), root_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
      <%= link_to root_path, class: "nav-link" do %>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= render "shared/dropdown_language" %>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li><%= link_to t('.rules_link'), rules_path, class: "nav-link active" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to t('.staff_link'), staff_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li>
          <% if user_signed_in?%>
            <%= render "shared/dropdown_menu" %>
            <li class="nav-link">
              <%# link_to t('.log_out_link'), destroy_user_session_path, data: {turbo_method: :delete}, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, data: {turbo_method: :delete}, class: "dropdown-item" do %>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket" style="color: #000000;"></i>
              <% end %>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to t('.login_link'), new_user_session_path, class: "nav-link" %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> %>
    <title><%= meta_title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="<%= meta_description %>">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag "favicon.png", rel: "icon", type: "image/png" %>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <%# javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <%= render "shared/navbar" %>
      <%= render "shared/flashes" %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-wrap">
      <%= render "shared/footer" %>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

and my routes (reduced for clarity's sake) :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr|nl/ do
    root to: "pages#home"
    get "rules", to: "pages#rules", as: "rules"
    get "staff", to: "pages#staff", as: "staff"

    resources :boxes, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```